# How can I use my angular keycloak configuration with a idphint attribute?

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using the angular keycloak adapter (https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular) to establish a connection to our keycloak server. This is working very well.

Now, I am trying to use the idphint attribute to delegate the request to a different idp.

**Question**:  The login() method has a possibility to add the idphint attribute, but I am not sure how to combine my implementation with this login method. Any suggestions?

**My implementation:**

```
export function initAuth(authService: KeycloakAuthenticationService): () => void {
  return () => authService.init({
    config: {
      url: KEYCLOAK_AUTH_URL,
      realm: 'Example-REALM',
      clientId: 'angular-client'
    },
    initOptions: {
      onLoad: 'login-required',
      checkLoginIframe: false
    }
  });
}
```

```
@NgModule({
 ...
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initAuth, multi: true, deps: [KeycloakAuthenticationService]}
  ]
...
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit the same wall just now and did some research which i wanted to note here for others. 
In principal you could provide the idpHint when calling the login() function, AFTER the adapter is initialized but before you are logged in (or else the first login attemp will not have the provider in the loginUrl.
So i supoose you would have to use the init() method and manually check for the login status to either manually log in or not...

After some research i decided for this solution instead and wrap around the login method to add my idpHint the hard way:

```js
const keycloakInit: KeycloakInit = {
  onLoad: 'login-required',
  flow: 'implicit'
};
const keycloakLoginParams = {
  idpHint: 'XXX-YYY'
};

export const environment: EnvironmentData = {
  production: false,
  keycloakJsUrl,
  keycloakConfig,
  keycloakInit,
  keycloakLoginParams,
  ...
};
```

```js
  private initKeycloak(resolve, reject) {
    if (!environment.keycloakConfig) {
      reject('keycloak config missing, but init triggered. reject');
    }

    this.keycloakAuth = new Keycloak(environment.keycloakConfig);

    if (environment.keycloakLoginParams) {
      // wrap an custom function around original login to support idpHint
      const kcLogin = this.keycloakAuth.login;
      this.keycloakAuth.login = (options) => {
        Object.assign(options, environment.keycloakLoginParams);
        kcLogin(options);
      };
    }

    this.keycloakAuth.init(environment.keycloakInit || {onLoad: 'login-required'})
      .success(() => {
        const tokenParsed = this.tokenParsed;
        this.user = this.createUserObject(tokenParsed);
        console.log('logged in', this.user, tokenParsed);
        resolve();
      })
      .error((resp) => {
        reject(resp.error + ': ' + resp.error_description);
      });

    // called when the access token is expired. we use implicit flow, just show login mask
    this.keycloakAuth.onTokenExpired = () => {
      this.redirectToLogin();
    };

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

keycloak-angular has an open issue to support the idpHint by adding the functionality to add KeycloakLoginOptions to the init method of keycloak-angular: https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular/issues/334

If they fix that issue, we can just use the KeycloakService.init(...) method from keycloak-angular instead of having to write our own init method.